# How to rearrange table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table look like this in DataFrame:

| couriers | delivery | price_list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alfred Locker | 2 day(s) | HKD $20 |
| Hongkong Post | 2 day(s) | HKD $50 |
| ZTO Express (To-Point) | 2 day(s) | HKD $20 |
| Zeek2Door (To Home) | 2 day(s) | HKD $40 |
| Kerry Express | 2 day(s) | HKD $30 |

I would like to rearrange the table like below:

| couriers_1 | delivery_1 | price_list_1 | couriers_2 | delivery_2 | price_list_2 | couriers_3 | delivery_3 | price_list_3 | couriers_4 | delivery_4 | price_list_4 | couriers_5 | delivery_5 | price_list_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alfred Locker | 2 day(s) | HKD $20 | Hongkong Post | 2 day(s) | HKD $50 | ZTO Express (To-Point) | 2 day(s) | HKD $20 | Zeek2Door (To Home) | 2 day(s) | HKD $40 | Kerry Express | 2 day(s) | HKD $30 |

How can I use Pandas to solve this? I can't figure it out!

Data:

```
{'couriers': ['Alfred Locker',
  'Hongkong Post',
  'ZTO Express (To-Point)',
  'Zeek2Door (To Home)',
  'Kerry Express'],
 'delivery': ['2 day(s)', '2 day(s)', '2 day(s)', '2 day(s)', '2 day(s)'],
 'price_list': ['HKD $20', 'HKD $50', 'HKD $20', 'HKD $40', 'HKD $30']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could `unstack` + convert MultiIndex to a plain index + `transpose`:

```
s = df.unstack().sort_index(level=1)
s.index = [f'{x}_{y+1}' for x,y in s.index]
out = s.to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
      couriers_1 delivery_1 price_list_1     couriers_2 delivery_2    price_list_2              couriers_3 delivery_3 price_list_3              couriers_4 delivery_4 price_list_4     couriers_5 delivery_5    price_list_5  
0  Alfred Locker   2 day(s)      HKD $20  Hongkong Post   2 day(s)         HKD $50  ZTO Express (To-Point)   2 day(s)      HKD $20     Zeek2Door (To Home)   2 day(s)      HKD $40  Kerry Express   2 day(s)         HKD $30
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a loop iterate over every element then use concat of pandas to attach each of them in order to form the data frame .

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(
["couriers", "Alfred Locker","Hongkong Post","ZTO Express(To-Point)","Zeek2Door(To Home)","Kerry Express"],
["delivery","2 day(s)","2 day(s)","2 day(s)","2 day(s)","2 day(s)"],
["price_list","HKD $20","HKD $50","HKD $20","HKD $40","HKD $30"],
))

counter_str = 1
#initialzing the df_result
df_result = ""
#iterating over the length so that we can add it to the string


for x in range(1,len(df)):
    for i in df:
        df_local = pd.DataFrame({df[i][0]+"_"+ str(x) : [df[i][counter_str]]})
        if len(df_result)>0:
            df_result = pd.concat([df_result,df_local], axis = 1, join='inner')
        else:
            df_result = df_local
    counter_str+=1

print(df_result)
```

Output:

```
    couriers_1 delivery_1 price_list_1  ...     couriers_5 delivery_5 price_list_5
0  Alfred Locker   2 day(s)      HKD $20  ...  Kerry Express   2 day(s)      HKD $30
```